# How to return multiple types from single method

Tags: java, overloading, inner-classes, return-type

I have a class named as **Boss** which contains different inner classes for diffrent types of bosses for my game . I have a *Main* class which uses a method **getBoss()** of Boss class ,to retrive appropriate boss class object as per current running level.

i.e. if level = 1 then "level1 boss" will arrive in the game. **Boss** class uses **level** variable to choose inner boss Classes.
this is what i m trying to do, but the problem is **getBoss()** is made to return objects of inner classes of Boss

```
Class Boss extends Sprite{
 public static Level3Boss l3;
 public static Level1Boss l1;
 public stati  Level2Boss l2;

 //Constructor
 public Boss(int level){
  if(level == 1){
    l1 = new Level1Boss();
     }
  else if(level = 2){
    l2 = new Level2Boss();
   }else{
    l3 = new Level3Boss();
   }
 }

 Class Level1Boss extends Sprite{
   //XYZ Propeties of this boss
  }

 Class Level2Boss extends Sprite{
   //XYZ Propeties of this boss
 }

 Class Level3Boss extends Sprite{
   //XYZ Propeties of this boss
   }

   public /*What to type here*/ getBoss(){
        if(level == 1){
         return l1;
       }
      else if(level = 2){
        return l2;
       }else{
        return l3;
      }
    }

}
```

So the confusion is what to write there at the place of return_type

```
  1.Level1Boss for ex: public Level1Boss getBoss(){}

   2.Level2Boss for ex: public Level2Boss getBoss(){}

   3.Level3Boss for ex: public Level2Boss getBoss(){}

  4.or something else ?
```

Is there any way by which i can return any of this 3 objects of different classes from getBoss() method

One more thing i tried return_type "Object" it just works but it cant be used in setting the images and drawing it on the full screen window.

So thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a class Boss and let Level1-2-3Boss extend it.

Example:

```
public abstract class Boss{
    public abstract int getX();
    public abstract int getY();
    public abstract int getZ();
}

public class Level1Boss extends Boss{
    ... (implement the abstract methods)
}

public Boss getBoss(){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're currently using the Boss class like a factory, so start by making that more declarative:

```java
public class BossFactory
{
   private Map<Integer,Boss> bosses = new HashMap<Integer,Boss>();

   public Boss getBoss(int level)
   {
      Boss resultBoss = bosses.get(level);
      if (resultBoss == null)
      {
         // create the boss
         // ideally this would be dynamically instantiated, but  fine for now
         if (level == 1)
         {
             resultBoss = new Level1Boss();
         }
         else if (level == 2)
         {
             resultBoss = new Level2Boss();
         }
         // store the boss
         bosses.put(level, resultBoss);
      }
      return resultBoss;
   }
}
```

Then turn your level bosses into a proper hierarchy of objects:

```
class Boss extends Sprite { }
class Level1Boss extends Boss {}
class Level2Boss extends Boss {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `Sprite`, since it is common to each class.

I would prefer to create new subtype, or type interface (e.g. `IBoss`), which would group all "bosses". That would be more explicit and easy to understand solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a Superclass , let say Level be a Superclass , and all level class extends it , then you can place Level as return type , as you said u tried with Object , but Object will not have methods of these class , so You can give Level as a superclass and all three level class extends it , now when u return and call any method on it , it will call the overridden method of that class , Level 1,2,3

```
Class Level {}

Class Level1Boss extends Level
{
        //its methods
}

Class Level2Boss extends Level
{
        //its methods
}

Class Level3Boss extends Level
{
        //its methods
}

now when you do this

public Level getBoss(){
        if(level == 1){
         return l1;
       }
      else if(level = 2){
        return l2;
       }else{
        return l3;
      }
    }
```

Then at runtime , this Level object reference will have the reference of its subclasses

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the common parent of the 3 classes, `Sprite` and then cast it back to  the original class

```
public Sprite getBoss(){
    if(level == 1){
        return l1;
    }
    else if(level = 2){
        return l2;
    } else{
        return l3;
    }
}

...
Sprite s = getBoss();
if( s instanceof Level1Boss ) {
    ((Level1Boss)s).whatever1();
} else if( s instanceof Level2Boss ) {
    ((Level2Boss)s).whatever2();
} else if( s instanceof Level3Boss ) {
    ((Level3Boss)s).whatever3();
} else {
    // error
}
```

It is similar to the popular method `findViewById(id)`. It returns a `View`, but you can cast it to whatever widget is really is.

Answer (score 0):

**First** : you will return `Sprite` . like this :

```
 public Sprite getBoss() {
        if (level == 1) {
            return l1;
        } else if (level = 2) {
            return l2;
        } else {
            return l3;
        }
    }
```

**Second** : `class` in java written with small character , not `Class`

**Finally** :  use `==` in if statement not `=` , like that :

```
 else if (level == 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare it in your final page and call direct the function names like this:

```
public static Level3Boss l3;
public static Level1Boss l1;
public static  Level2Boss l2;


    Level3Boss= Boss.Getl3();
    Level1Boss= Boss.Getl1();
    Level2Boss= Boss.Getl2();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a relation between a `Boss` and a `Level`. You have to think about the relation then make your architecture.

Anyway, I suggest you to summarize (abstract) as much as possible your code and your architecture. [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) in Java will help you.

```
public abstract class Boss extends Sprite {
 public int strength;
 public int name;
 ...
}

public class Level {
 public int number;
 public Boss boss;
 ...
}
```

Define some Boss

```
public class Megatron extends Boss{

}
```

You don't need to abstract a Level. An instance of this class should be enough for each level.

```
Boss megatron = new Megatron(100, "Megatron");
Level level1 = new Level(1, megatron);
```